# Can't get Free Jquery Slider to work

Tags: javascript, jquery

So i have found this Free Jquery slider that i want to add to my webpage. 
https://newsignature.com/jcoverflip

I have followed the installation guide provided: https://github.com/NewSignature/jcoverflip

yet when i do this HTML inside the body:

```
<ul id="flip">
<li><a><img src="England.png"><span class="title">My title</span></a></li>
<li><a><img src="Denmark.png"><span class="title">My title</span></a></li>

</ul>
<script>
$(function(){
$('#flip').jcoverclip();
});
</script>
```

And this inside head:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.ui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.jcoverflip.js"></script>
```

and this in my css:

```
.ui-jcoverflip {position: relative;}
.ui-jcoverflip--item {position: absolute; display: block;}
```

yet the only thing im getting out of this is two pictures on top of eachother with no interaction at all.

I have added Jquery 2.1.4 and Jquery ui 1.11.4 custom and Jcoverflip to my project folder.

Can anyone confirm that this slider works and what i am doing wrong?

Thanks for any contributions in advance

Comment: Do you get any errors inside the javascript console?

Comment: Errors in the console? Can you make an example with the libraries loaded as a snipplet?

Comment: Have you included `jQuery` library?

Comment: Also be aware, that the Github page states: `jCoverflip has not been updated to work with the most recent versions of jQuery and jQuery UI! Proceed with caution!` .. The code has last been updated 5 years ago... That's the equivalent of a lightyear on the web. Perhaps you'll have more luck if you try with an old jQuery 1.7- .. or just find a newer plugin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change:

```
$('#flip').jcoverclip();
```

To:

```
$('#flip').jcoverflip();
```

Comment: @Brutiquzz there's a mistype in the documentation

Comment: sorry thats not it. Same result. I have copy pasted this from the guide and it says clip and not flip. Though it makes perfect sense it should be flip and not clip.

Comment: @Brutiquzz, not necessarily saying that it's the answer, but the guide is wrong - even if this isn't the issue, it will *never* work with `jcoverclip` - check the source code

Comment: @Brutiquzz in fact, here is issue submitted to the github repository for the exact issue: https://github.com/NewSignature/jcoverflip/issues/1

Comment: alright i got it! Thx m8! but as i said i still only have two pictures on top of eachother with no slide show

Comment: with an older version jquery and your change clip to flip it finally works!